# How can i close my iframe Fancybox and return to parent page in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

How can I close my iframe Fancybox and return to parent page in selenium webdriver? I am using iframe to upload an image and i need to submit my from on parent page.

```
WebElement browse_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='myForm1']/input[2]"));
browse_btn.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\test1.jpg");
WebElement upload_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='myForm1']/input[3]"));
upload_btn.click();
WebElement progress_bar=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bar']")) ;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='percent']"), "100%"));
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. You don't even need the Thread.sleep(5000) as well, as the DOM is already present. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Where's your code where you attempt to close the dialog? It should be where the sleep is. I don't see why you need the `defaultContent()` line... you don't have any code where you switch context into an iframe. We also need a link to the page or the relevant HTML posted.

Comment: @Dev There is no error ,but the iframe is not getting closed amd i am unable to access the elements of parent page

Comment: @AakritiRanjan Can you update, while trying manually to upload a file how does the FancyBox gets closed? The same should happen when you try with WebDriver. Can you add a screenshot and update your question? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you `Thread.sleep(5000)` even after upload is complete? Does the frame window gets closed automatically? 
If not, is there any close button to close the frame?

Not sure with your scenario here, you can try  `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();` instead of `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`. This might work.

Comment: No,the window is not getting closed automatically . I removed thread.sleep() and tried driver.switchTo.parentframe(); ,but iframe is not switching to parent window.